# determining if a div is a parent

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have this HTML structure:

```
<div id="Ancestor">
 <div>
   <div>
     ....
       <div class="DeepChild"></div>
...
<div id="NotAncestor">
 <div>
   <div>
     ....
       <div class="DeepChild"></div>
```

I want to know, when I click on a DeepChild div if it's a descendant of Ancestor.

Something like this:

```
$('.DeepChild').click(function () {
   if (whichcondition?? === true) { IsFromAncestor = true; }
});
```

Comment: You might want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10828640/601179)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(this).parents("#Ancestor").length > 0
```

If your parenthood class is static and doesn't move over time, you may want to attach the listener only to the div who are nested in and ancestor:

```
$("#Ancestor .deepchild").click(...
```

Comment: by the way, .parents(...) will look through the different levels of parents (as opposed to .parent(...), which only looks one level higher).

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question, and has an accepted answer already, but I think the best options wasn't given yet:

<s>$(this).parents("#Ancestor").length > 0</s>  Might be **very slow** for complex DOM structure.

```
if ($('#Ancestor').find(this).length)
    //I'm under the  #Ancestor.
```

[**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/parents-vs-id-with-id/edit) showing my way is **three times faster**!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
$(this).parents("#Ancestor").length > 0
```